# How can I save my current workbook content and send to my file system with OfficeJS?

Tags: excel, office-js

We want to saved the current opened workbook into in our own cloud file system for download later, back-end processing, or report distribution. How can I do this with OfficeJS getFileAsync API?

Answer (score 1):

Here the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word) described how to use getFileAsync to get file object and then send to customer's server endpoint with http request.

Here is [sample gist](https://gist.github.com/gingerjia/748c1fdbf23a16ffc9b6b0bbb18520a1) to create a new workbook with base64 string from getFileAsync API.